# Where to put ReactDOM.render in React

Tags: reactjs

Here is the [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) example of react, in the example, the bellow code fragment is in separate **main.js** file:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

What if there are pages that don't contain id: 'example', e.g. home.html(only have id:example1), index.html(only have id:example2), then how to reuse `<h1>Hello, world!</h1>` in those pages ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a valid problem. You can abstract the hard coded #id part from the main.js file. Instead of thinking main.js as a self bootstrapping React app, just expose a parametric version of it.

Here is new main.js

```
window.renderApp = function(id){
  ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById(id)
  );
};
```

And in your presumably index.html file

```
<div id="newID"></div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script>
  renderApp('newID');
</script>
```

I have seen this approach used, and I myself used this in several production React apps. Basically it is not logical to bind your React app with a hard coded id parameter.

Comment: Have you got the error: ReferenceError: renderApp is not defined when using webpack to build react?

Comment: it should be `window.renderApp = function(id){
  ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById(id)
  );
}`

Comment: @fudy, yes you are correct, but it is not good practice to output by assigning to window global variable. Best is to use output.libraryTarget and output.library to control how you expose your functionality. For the sake of simplicity, I will update my example to use window method. Thanks.

Comment: @KemalDağ you saved my day! Cheers Bro :)

Answer (score 4):

Kemal's answer is a good one, I just wanted to share my solution to this.

These days rather than hooking directly on to `window` or similar, I will expose a static `init(id, props)` method on my top level component that performs the initial mounting:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    ...
    static init(id, props) {
        return ReactDOM.render(
            <App {...props} />,
            document.getElementById(id)
        );
    }
    ...
}
```

And then in my hosting page:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
App.init('container', { ... });
</script>
```

Comment: This looks much better than Kernal's approach, but I'm getting "App is not defined" - There is no "App" in the compiled JS file

Answer (score 0):

The `#example` element is just a mounting point for the app. Check out the [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) where you will learn how to compose basic components. Then later on you can change between pages/views using a router for example.

Comment: I have read that tutorial, but anyway you need to render your component, usually, will render by id. then if the code is in the separate js file, how can I include it in other page and render multiple div

Comment: You will only render the application's parent component which in turn will also render all its child components – thus rendering the whole app inside the `#example` element.

Comment: My question is how to render parent component in different pages or multiple times in one page

Comment: Why would you need to render the parent component multiple times on one page? You can render content based on URL using one of the router modules. Or if you need to have multiple html files and varying IDs, you can use an approach like Kemal suggested.

Comment: Just want to reuse  one component, I also prefer the way Kemal suggested.