# React not rendering anything on the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have just started learning ReactJS and made my first app by following a tutorial but nothing is rendered on the screen when I run the html file.

index.js

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="root">
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked browser's console to see if there's any error?

Comment: Hope this helps.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35056737/7785337

Comment: How did you create your `React App`? Did you use `create-react-app` or you start from scratch?

Comment: Atin Singh There is no error in the console but if I don't write "text/babel" it gives an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module". And when I write this I can't see my JS file in the Sources tab.

Comment: Taghi Khavari I started from the scratch

Answer (score 0):

Here I think you need to write your code in the form of function which would be called from the HTML file.

So you need to update your index.js to:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

window.printHello = function(id){
   ReactDOM.render(
   <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
   document.getElementById(id)
   );
 }
```

And your html file should be updated to the below code:

```
<div id="hello"></div>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script>
 printHello('hello');
</script>
```

Comment: If I don't specify type="text/babel" in the script tag it gives the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" and when I use it, "Uncaught ReferenceError: printHello is not defined at index.html:7" appears.

Comment: I have added the other solution for your question below. Please refer it once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution for your query.
There is no need to add the script tag in your HTML.

If the js and HTML are part of the same component you can just use the id directly in the HTML.
So your updated code for js and HTML would be be somewhat like this.

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

And the HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this would be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was `ReactDOM` getting imported from different module. After updating the import statement from

```
import ReactDOM from "react";
```

to

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
```

in `index.js` file worked.